# jest: how to mock a dependency that listens to events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-promise

I came across a very complicated situation. *I'll try to keep it as concise as possible.*

So I have a code like this in **myModule.js**:

```
const lib = require('@third-party/lib');

const myFunction = () => {
  const client = lib.createClient('foo');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
    client.on('success', () => {
      client.as(param1).post(param2, param3, (err, data) => {
        if (err) reject(err);

        // Some important logical processing of data
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  });
}

module.exports = { myFunction };
```

There are a few things I am able to mock, like: `createClient`. 
What I am not able to mock is the event part *I don't even know how to do this.* And the `.as().post()` part.

Here's how my **jest test** looks like:

```
const myModule = require('./myModule');
const mockData = require('./mockData');

describe('myFunction', () => {

  it('Should resolve promise when lib calls success event', async () => {
    try {
      const myData = await myModule.myFunction();
      expect(myData).toMatchObject(mockData.resolvedData);
    } catch (err) {
      expect(err).toBeNull();
    }
  })
});
```

Any help, much Appreciated.

I tried to find similar questions but at this point, my mind has just stopped working... 
Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, do you need to mock `success` event with a `post` callback returning data. Do I get this right?

Comment: In a way, YES. I also want to mock the error event. But if you give me the solution to success I will figure it out from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s what you need to do:

```
// EventEmitter is here to rescue you
const events = require("events");

// Mock the third party library
const lib = require("@third-party/lib");

lib.createClient.mockImplementationOnce(params => {
  const self = new events.EventEmitter();

  self.as = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    // Since we're calling post on the same object.
    return self;
  });

  self.post = jest.fn().mockImplementation((arg1, _cb) => {
    // Can have a conditional check for arg 1 if so desird
    _cb(null, { data : "foo" });
  });

  // Finally call the required event with delay.
  // Don't know if the delay is necessary or not.
  setInterval(() => {
    self.emit("success");
  }, 10);
  return self;
}).mockImplementationOnce(params => {
  const self = new events.EventEmitter();

  // Can also simulate event based error like so:
  setInterval(() => {
    self.emit("error", {message: "something went wrong."});
  }, 10);
  return self;
}).mockImplementationOnce(params => {
  const self = new events.EventEmitter();
  self.as = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return self;
  });

  self.post = jest.fn().mockImplementation((arg1, _cb) => {
    // for negative callback in post I did:
    _cb({mesage: "Something went wrong"}, null);
  });

  setInterval(() => {
    self.emit("success");
  }, 10);
  return self;
});
```

This is only the mock object that you need to put in your ***test.js*** file.

Not sure if this code will work as is, although won’t require a lot of debugging.

If you just want to positive scenario, remove  the second `mockImplementationOnce` and replace the first `mockImplementationOnce` with just `mockImplementation`.

Comment: I had to make some changes according to my logic. Although the answer worked for me perfectly.